# How to force SQL to treat " - - " as a single delimiter?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to delimit @uid by "-". The issue is my data set has "--1" and I need it be treated as "-1"

I need @uid = '1585-1586--1-5417-2347-8865' to output this:

[image]

Instead of:

[image]

How can I achieve this in SQL?

Comment: Using a delimiter that can also appear in your data is often a recipe for problems. Choosing a different delimiter would solve the problem.

Comment: *Don't* store denormalized data in a database to begin with. Parse and clean the data *before* inserting it in the database. In this case, you can't just split the text to get the data,you need a regex or a simple parser to handle the unfortunate delimiter

Comment: I agree with both comments but I'm going to assume that this is a data dump and the OP is asking for a query for ETL purposes. ;-)

Comment: @LarryB something best done by the ETL tool, not SQL. That's what the acronym means too, Extract Transform and only then Load. Even if the OP wants to load first, then transform (ELT), parsing is a *lot* easier using other languages

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos your comment was on my mind recently. Again, I agree wholeheartedly, but I assume that the OP realizes that the best case scenario is not available to them due to time constraints and limited resources. I've never been shown table structures and examples of data in a job interview. The comments I tend to see are the "as per usual" variety because we should educate and provide solutions, that's cool. I've never worked for a company where the data isn't denormalized or something else stupid. Cleaning it requires bureaucracy, and by that time I'm submitting my resume elsewhere.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The desired result can be achieve with the script below. The script relies on a User Defined Function called [fnSplit]. The [fnSplit] UDF is defined later in the post.

```
declare @uid nvarchar(100)
set @uid = '1585-1586--1-5417-2347-8865'

select
(select  data from   [dbo].[fnSplit] (REPLACE ((REPLACE (@uid, '-', '|')),'||', '|-'), '|') where id = 1) as [Col_A],
(select  data from   [dbo].[fnSplit] (REPLACE ((REPLACE (@uid, '-', '|')),'||', '|-'), '|') where id = 2) as [Col_B],
(select  data from   [dbo].[fnSplit] (REPLACE ((REPLACE (@uid, '-', '|')),'||', '|-'), '|') where id = 3) as [Col_C],
(select  data from   [dbo].[fnSplit] (REPLACE ((REPLACE (@uid, '-', '|')),'||', '|-'), '|') where id = 4) as [Col_D],
(select  data from   [dbo].[fnSplit] (REPLACE ((REPLACE (@uid, '-', '|')),'||', '|-'), '|') where id = 5) as [Col_E],  
(select  data from   [dbo].[fnSplit] (REPLACE ((REPLACE (@uid, '-', '|')),'||', '|-'), '|') where id = 6) as [Col_F]
```

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit]
(
    @Line nvarchar(MAX),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(5) = ','
)
RETURNS @RtnValue table
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Data nvarchar(1000) NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Line IS NULL RETURN

    DECLARE @split_on_len INT = LEN(@SplitOn)
    DECLARE @start_at INT = 1
    DECLARE @end_at INT
    DECLARE @data_len INT

    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        SET @end_at = CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@Line,@start_at)
        SET @data_len = CASE @end_at WHEN 0 THEN LEN(@Line) ELSE @end_at-@start_at END
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (data) VALUES( SUBSTRING(@Line,@start_at,@data_len) );
        IF @end_at = 0 BREAK;
        SET @start_at = @end_at + @split_on_len
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: What is `fnSplit`?

Comment: @Larnu I believe it's a UDF from some package which basically does the same things as `STRING_SPLIT` in more recent versions of SQL Server.

Comment: I guessed that, @TimBiegeleisen , but without the definition, this answer is useless to future readers.

Comment: Instead of a custom `fnSplit` one could use an R or Python parsing script. It would probably take fewer lines than this answer, and R works in all current SQL Server versions (ie 2016 and later, I think even 2014 is out of mainstream support)

Comment: Even with that unknown `fnSplit` method, PIVOT could convert the rows to columns without requiring repeated splits like this. It would be 6 times faster.

Comment: @larnu the UDF was added. Forgot to added to the original post.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please post an example of what you have in mind. I am not familiar with R

Comment: That uses a `WHILE`, @user716255 , a *really* show way to split a string SQL Server. There are far faster ways that using an iterative method.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you have helps you a little here, however, with no definition of `[dbo].[fnSplit]` doesn't help any one else.

If we can **assume** that the data is well defined (has 6 columns), then we could "spam" some `CHARINDEX` functions to do this. You will, as shown in the answer, need to replace all the delimiters and then reinsert the value of `-` for the double delimiter:

```
DECLARE @UID varchar(30) = '1585-1586--1-5417-2347-8865';

DECLARE @Delimiter char(1) = '-';

SELECT SUBSTRING(ca.FixedUID,1,C1.I-1) AS Col1,
       SUBSTRING(ca.FixedUID,C1.I+1, C2.I-C1.I-1) AS Col2,
       SUBSTRING(ca.FixedUID,C2.I+1, C3.I-C2.I-1) AS Col3,
       SUBSTRING(ca.FixedUID,C3.I+1, C4.I-C3.I-1) AS Col4,
       SUBSTRING(ca.FixedUID,C4.I+1, C5.I-C4.I-1) AS Col5,
       SUBSTRING(ca.FixedUID,C5.I+1, LEN(ca.FixedUID)-C5.I) AS Col6
FROM (VALUES(@UID))V([UID])
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(REPLACE(V.UID,@Delimiter,'|'),'||','|' + @Delimiter)))ca(FixedUID)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('|',ca.FixedUID)))C1(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('|',ca.FixedUID,C1.I+1)))C2(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('|',ca.FixedUID,C2.I+1)))C3(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('|',ca.FixedUID,C3.I+1)))C4(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('|',ca.FixedUID,C4.I+1)))C5(I);
```

Of course, if you had a "empty" value, then this will fail:

```
DECLARE @UID varchar(30) = '1585--71-5417-2347-8865';

DECLARE @Delimiter char(1) = '-';

SELECT SUBSTRING(ca.FixedUID,1,C1.I-1) AS Col1,
       SUBSTRING(ca.FixedUID,C1.I+1, C2.I-C1.I-1) AS Col2,
       SUBSTRING(ca.FixedUID,C2.I+1, C3.I-C2.I-1) AS Col3,
       SUBSTRING(ca.FixedUID,C3.I+1, C4.I-C3.I-1) AS Col4,
       SUBSTRING(ca.FixedUID,C4.I+1, C5.I-C4.I-1) AS Col5,
       SUBSTRING(ca.FixedUID,C5.I+1, LEN(ca.FixedUID)-C5.I) AS Col6
FROM (VALUES(@UID))V([UID])
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(REPLACE(V.UID,@Delimiter,'|'),'||','|' + @Delimiter)))ca(FixedUID)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('|',ca.FixedUID)))C1(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('|',ca.FixedUID,C1.I+1)))C2(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('|',ca.FixedUID,C2.I+1)))C3(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('|',ca.FixedUID,C3.I+1)))C4(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('|',ca.FixedUID,C4.I+1)))C5(I);
```

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

And hence why a delimiter than can appear in your data should never be used (however, one can hope that as these all appear to be integer values then a `NULL` value wouldn't exist and there would be a `0` instead: `'1585-0-71-5417-2347-8865'`).

If you used a string splitter like [`DelimitedSpluit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) then you could Pivot (and unpivot) the data fine, but the values would be in the wrong positions with the above example:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE DS.ItemNumber WHEN 1 THEN DS.Item END) AS Col1,
       MAX(CASE DS.ItemNumber WHEN 2 THEN DS.Item END) AS Col2,
       MAX(CASE DS.ItemNumber WHEN 3 THEN DS.Item END) AS Col3,
       MAX(CASE DS.ItemNumber WHEN 4 THEN DS.Item END) AS Col4,
       MAX(CASE DS.ItemNumber WHEN 5 THEN DS.Item END) AS Col5,
       MAX(CASE DS.ItemNumber WHEN 6 THEN DS.Item END) AS Col6
FROM (VALUES(@UID))V([UID])
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(REPLACE(V.UID,@Delimiter,'|'),'||','|' + @Delimiter)))ca(FixedUID)
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(ca.FixedUID,'|') DS;
```

Which will result in the below:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
1585 -71  5417 2347 8865 NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what I'm doing is a recursive cte from 6 to 1. each iteration I am removing the last delimited number and moving it to `col_val` column. 
I decided to use `reverse` so that I could then use `patindex` to find the hyphen then the number. Doing that made it possible to get the negative values. In reverse the string looks like 1--6851-5851-0 then `patindex('%-[0-9]%', <string>)` returns 2 and because I used `right` function of the string 0-1585-1586--1 it will return -1

I added `'0-'` to the beginning of the `delim_column` because I want to use `patindex` without having to account for the last delimited column.

The column `col_val` is repeating all the above but instead of using `@uid` it is using `delim_column`

Here is what each iteration looks like:

```
col_num     delim_column                col_val     loc
6           0-1585-1586--1-5417-2347    8865        4
5           0-1585-1586--1-5417         2347        4
4           0-1585-1586--1              5417        4
3           0-1585-1586                 -1          2
2           0-1585                      1586        4
1           0                           1585        4
```

Then I'm pivoting the columns using a simple choose function. That will make the column names clean.

```
DECLARE
    @uid VARCHAR(MAX) = '1585-1586--156-5417-2347-8865',
    @delim_count INT = 0

--First, count the number of delimiters. We do this by temporarily replacing '--' with a single '-'
--and then count the difference in lengths of the two strings (one with '-' and one without)

SELECT @delim_count = LEN(REPLACE(@uid, '--', '-')) - LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(@uid, '--', '-'), '-','')) - IIF(@uid LIKE '-%', 1, 0)

--next a recursive cte that will lop off the last number each iteration and move the last value to col_val
;WITH fnsplit(col_num, delim_column, col_val, loc)
AS
(
    SELECT 
        @delim_count+1    --start with 6 and then go to 1. remove the +1 and replace col_num > 0 for a zero index
        ,'0-'+SUBSTRING(@uid,0, LEN(@uid) - LEN(RIGHT(@uid, PATINDEX('%-[0-9]%', reverse(@uid)) - 1)) )
        ,RIGHT(@uid, PATINDEX('%-[0-9]%', REVERSE(@uid)) - 1)
        ,PATINDEX('%-[0-9]%', REVERSE(@uid)) - 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
         col_num - 1
        ,SUBSTRING(delim_column,0, LEN(delim_column) - LEN(RIGHT(delim_column, PATINDEX('%-[0-9]%', REVERSE(delim_column)) - 1)) )
        ,RIGHT(delim_column, PATINDEX('%-[0-9]%', REVERSE(delim_column)) - 1)
        ,PATINDEX('%-[0-9]%', REVERSE(delim_column)) - 1
    FROM 
        fnsplit
    WHERE 
        col_num > 1
)

--select * from fnsplit   -- uncomment here and comment all below to see the recursion 

SELECT 
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
         column_name
        ,col_val
    FROM
        fnsplit
    CROSS APPLY
        (SELECT CHOOSE(col_num, 'Col_A','Col_B','Col_C', 'Col_D', 'Col_E', 'Col_F')) tbl(column_name)
)PVT
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(col_val)
            FOR column_name IN ([Col_A], [Col_B], [Col_C], [Col_D], [Col_E], [Col_F])
    ) PVT1
```